# model class inheritance (problem with view)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 model classes with different attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Subuser < User
end
```

When I call the 'new' function within controller:

```
def new
 @subuser = Subuser.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @hosting }
  end
end
```

and try to access data with view thats held by the Subuser model (migration):

```
<% form_for(@subuser) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :subname %>
<% end %>
```

I get:

undefined method `subname' for #

However, if I change it to some other cell that is defined under User model/migration, it will all work okay.

It seems like there are some isssues with the data access.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

I get the following error

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted, `@hosting` is only defined for `format=xml`, it won't exist for the HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

What is the @hosting variable supposed to be?  Mike is right, you aren't defining it anywhere.

My guess is that you probably want to do something more along the lines of

```
form_for(@subuser) do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are properly using STI (single table inheritance) here? What is your schema for the users table?  Are you saying that you have a migration for Subuser... because if you are trying to use STI, it should use the `users` table with a `type` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub model only knows what it is given via it's parent. So if your trying to access an "imaginary" attribute you will get that undefined method error.

Try added `attr_accessor :subname` to give it that attribute.

I'm also a bit curious about that @hosting thing...